# Radio input as a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, input

In the snippet below you will see that I am styling a radio button to look like a button. I am wanting these buttons to work just as the radio button would in its normal state. Right now both radio buttons are taking on the `active` class from my javascript on page load. This should only happen if they are selected.

Also, the `fadeToggle` from the `if-statement` that produces the extra input under the radio buttons is functioning as if the radio buttons are checkboxes. I have to click on the same button twice to de-activate it. I think this is based on the issue above.

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```js
var rsvpAns = $('.radioTransform');
rsvpAns.click(function() {
  $('.radio', this).prop('checked', !$('.radio', this).prop('checked')).change();
  var radioCheck = $('.radio', this).val();
  $('.radioTransform', this).toggleClass('active');
  console.log(radioCheck);
  if (radioCheck == 'Yes') {
    $('#ansYes').fadeToggle(400);
  }
});
```

```css
.radio {
  display: none;
}

#pushR {
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.radioTransform {
  width: 220px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #dbc8ca;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.radioTransform.active {
  background: red;
}

.radioAnswer {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: .9rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#ansYes {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="rsvpForm">
  <div class="formField">
    <div class="radioTransform" id="pushR">
      <span class="radioAnswer">YES</span>
      <input type="radio" value="Yes" class="radio">
    </div>
    <div class="radioTransform">
      <span class="radioAnswer">NO</span>
      <input type="radio" value="No" class="radio">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="formField" id="ansYes">
    <label class="label">How are you doing?</label>
    <input type="text" class="input">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You want it so both radio buttons can be checked at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Javascript at all for this - only some intelligent CSS and a slight restructuring of your markup. This change will even increase the semantic value and accessibility of your solution.

I have only added Javascript for some console.logging so you see the snippet works.

Please note that in order to make radio buttons work like expected, they need to share the `name` attribute, otherwise both can be "on".

```js
const radios = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name="yesno"]'))

for (const radio of radios) {
  radio.addEventListener('change', function() {
    value.textContent = document.querySelector('[name="yesno"]:checked').value
  })
}
```

```css
.radio {
  display: none;
}

.radioAnswer {
  width: 220px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #dbc8ca;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px 0;
  transition-duration: .4s;
  position: relative;
}

.radioAnswer::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: width .4s linear .1s, 
    height .2s linear 1.6s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(35deg) translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin: center right;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+.radioAnswer {
  background: #0a0;
  color: #fff;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+.radioAnswer::before {
  border-color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(35deg) translateY(-50%);
  height: 1.5em;
  width: .8em;
  transition: all .4s linear 0s, width .4s linear .1s, height .2s linear .3s
;  position: absolute;
}

.radioAnswer {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: .9rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" value="Yes" class="radio" name="yesno" id="yes">
<label class="radioAnswer" for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" value="No" class="radio" name="yesno" id="no">
<label class="radioAnswer" for="no">NO</label>
<p>Selected Value: <strong id="value"></strong></p>
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I get the value of the radio button then with JS?

Comment: `document.querySelector('input[name="yesno"]:checked').value;`

Comment: I've edited the answer to your question in the comments into the answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition block only works when you clicked yes button. Then what if you clicked No, for this condition you can have else statement. And here in this code `radioTransform` div don't have active class on load.

```js
var rsvpAns = $('.radioTransform');
rsvpAns.click(function() {
  $('.radio', this).prop('checked', !$('.radio', this).prop('checked')).change();
  var radioCheck = $('.radio', this).val();
  console.log(radioCheck);
  
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if (radioCheck == 'Yes') {
    $('#ansYes').fadeToggle(400);
   if($(this).next('.radioTransform').hasClass('active')){
    $(this).next('.radioTransform').removeClass('active');
   }
  } else {
    $('#ansYes').fadeOut(400);
  if($(this).prev('.radioTransform').hasClass('active')){
   $(this).prev('.radioTransform').removeClass('active');
   }
  }
});
```

```css
.radio {
  display: none;
}

#pushR {
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.radioTransform {
  width: 220px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #dbc8ca;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.radioTransform.active {
  background: red;
}

.radioAnswer {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: .9rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#ansYes {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="rsvpForm">
  <div class="formField">
    <div class="radioTransform" id="pushR">
      <span class="radioAnswer">YES</span>
      <input type="radio" value="Yes" class="radio">
    </div>
    <div class="radioTransform">
      <span class="radioAnswer">NO</span>
      <input type="radio" value="No" class="radio">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="formField" id="ansYes">
    <label class="label">How are you doing?</label>
    <input type="text" class="input">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed having `active` to the `radioTransform` class in my css. I just added the `active` class to my file and now the red background will not add when the radio button are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the toggling effect of the radio button with the backgrounds, `$('.radioTransform', this).toggleClass('active');` will not be enough.

First, taking into consideration it is already inside a click handler which is attached to `$('.radioTransform')`, when you add `this` as second argument of `$('.radioTransform', this).toggleClass('active');` you are telling it to look for `.radioTransform`s inside a `.radioTransform`, cause you are setting `.radioTransform` as the context of the selector, that's why it does not change color. And even if you remove `this`, you would be toggling the class for every `.radioTransform` there is (how many times did I write `radioTransform`?:) )

Second, remove `background: red` from `.radioTransform` when it is not active, else you will never see it happen

```js
var rsvpAns = $('.radioTransform');
rsvpAns.click(function() {
  $('.radio', this).prop('checked', !$('.radio', this).prop('checked')).change();
  var radioCheck = $('.radio', this).val();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).siblings('.radioTransform').toggleClass('active', !$(this).hasClass('active'));
  console.log(radioCheck);
  if (radioCheck == 'Yes') {
    $('#ansYes').fadeToggle(400);
  } else {
    $('#ansYes').fadeOut(400);
  }
});
```

```css
.radio {
 display: none;
}
#pushR {
 margin-right: 25px;
}
.radioTransform {
 width: 220px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 background: #dbc8ca;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 15px 0;
}
.radioTransform {
 /*background: red;*/
}
.radioAnswer {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: .9rem;
 text-align: center;
}
#ansYes {
  display: none;
}

.radioTransform.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="rsvpForm">
  <div class="formField">
    <div class="radioTransform" id="pushR">
      <span class="radioAnswer">YES</span>
      <input type="radio" value="Yes" class="radio">
    </div>
    <div class="radioTransform">
      <span class="radioAnswer">NO</span>
      <input type="radio" value="No" class="radio">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="formField" id="ansYes">
    <label class="label">How are you doing?</label>
    <input type="text" class="input">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" id="submit">
</form>
```